# What does this code do in a Google Maps web page

Tags: html, google-maps

I have modified some code (with permission from, [here](http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm)) to show longitude and latitude on my web site. I have a general idea on what most of the code does but there is one section that I have no idea and wonder if any of the gurus can tell me.  If.. it is some sort of reporting script I would like to be able to have it report to me.

The owner when asked informed me that he had "borrowed" most of the code as well and had no trouble with me using it. And.. as he was not a coder could not advise on any problems / questions I had.

```
//<![CDATA[

var gs_d=new Date,DoW=gs_d.getDay();gs_d.setDate(gs_d.getDate()-(DoW+6)%7+3);

var ms=gs_d.valueOf();gs_d.setMonth(0);gs_d.setDate(4);

var gs_r=(Math.round((ms-gs_d.valueOf())/6048E5)+1)*gs_d.getFullYear();

var gs_p = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");

document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gs_p + "s.gstat.orange.fr/lib/gs.js?"+gs_r+"' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

//]]>
```

Comment: Thanks.. as long as it is not something malicious I will stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 0):

The code comes from the [gStat project](http://www.gstat.org/) and is used in the generation ("prediction") of the lat & long locations.